# Parse KML loaded from network link on each Google Earth plugin movement

Tags: google-earth-plugin

Is there a way to parse a network links KML each time the Earth is moved. I know how to setup the eventListener.
Page flow: 
- I load the KML using fetchKml
- Each time the earth is moved it pulls the network stream
- I want to parse the streamed KML to see if it's within view limits or not so I can display a message.

So to summarize.  I want to somehow parse the returned KML from a network link to see if the features are within view and if no show a message like "Out of Range".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683122/lazy-demand-load-kml-in-google-maps-or-google-earth-plugin/8426431#8426431

Answer (score 0):

if you are generating the network link servier side you can use viewformat in kml to pass as parameters the current google earth view bounding box as parameters,

http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kmlreference.html#viewformat

if the view BBOX isn't in the desired area generate you could try return kml string consisting of a networklinkcontrol with a message

http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kmlreference.html#networklinkcontrol

the other option is define you data client side in an object, either on the page load and loop through on the data to see if things on the google earth plugin viewchangeend event.